# asp.net cookies not set into browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cookies, fetch

I am trying receive cookies in ASP.NET core API. When I am testing it in postman everything is working, but browser does not sends cookies back.

This is c# code which sets cookie in response.

```
 HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Test", "test value", new CookieOptions()
        {
            HttpOnly = false,
            Domain = "localhost",
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(10),
            IsEssential = true,
            Path = "/",
            Secure = false,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.MaxValue
        });
```

Here is js code

```
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
  myHeaders.append("credentials", "include");
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders
  };
  
  fetch("https://localhost:5001/api/user/get-authed-user", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

During debugging asp.net, there is not "Test" cookie in it when sending request from
browser.

Postman does it well and the "Test" cookie is visible during debugging.

Also I can not see cookies in browser (F12 -> Application -> cookies).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7o4G.png)

Comment: Where in c# are you setting the http header "Accept" and "credentials"?

Comment: I fixed it. After setting Secure property as true everything is working.